# Fazer item ficar destacado se for referente ao menu selecionado

Tags: jquery, html

Tenho o seguinte código

```
<div class="produtosMenuItens">
    <div class="produtosMenuItensTit bs">Residencial</div>
    <ul class="produtosMenuItensDiplay" style="display: block;">
        <li class="produtosMenuItensLista">ITEM 1</li>
        <li class="produtosMenuItensLista">ITEM 2</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="produtosMenuItensTit">Industrial</div>
<ul class="produtosMenuItensDiplay" style="display: none;">
    <li class="produtosMenuItensLista">ITEM 3</li>
    <li class="produtosMenuItensLista">ITEM 4</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Seguinte, aí há dois menus, quando eu selecionar o ITEM 1, e entrar na página em questão, eu quero que ele fique destacado, pode ser adicionando uma classe via Jquery, como faço isso?

O Jquery está assim:

```
$(".produtosMenuItensTit").click(function() {
    if($(this).parent().find(".produtosMenuItensDiplay").css('display') == 'none'){
        $(".produtosMenuItensDiplay").css('display','none');
        $(this).parent().find(".produtosMenuItensDiplay").show();
    }
    else{
        $(this).parent().find(".produtosMenuItensDiplay").hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Poderia explicar um pouco melhor a sua dúvida?

Comment: @FelipeAvelar eu esqueci de postar o Jquery, já inclui lá. Eu quero que quando eu clique no Menu, e abara a página ele fique mostrando na LI qual o item foi selecionado.

Answer (score 2):

Consegui!

**JQUERY**

```
$("[pagina]").each(function(index,element){
   var link = $(element).attr('pagina');
      if(menu.split(link).length>1){
        $(element).css({'color':'#0093C9','font-weight':'bold'});
}
```

**HTML**

```
<li pagina="paginaSYS" class="produtosMenuItensLista">BLABLABLA</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Se entendi bem, você pode adicionar uma classe para destacar o elemento clicado, exemplo:

**CSS**

```
 .active {background-color:red;}
```

**JQuery**

```
$('.produtosMenuItensLista').click(function(){
    //remove class active
    $('.produtosMenuItensLista').removeClass('active');
    //adiciona class active ao item clicado
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Er5er/2/)

Comment: ele aplica, mas acontece que ele carrega a página para abrir o menu logo depois

Comment: O menu também é recarregado quando clicado?

Comment: Sim, quando eu clico no ITEM, ele abre o menu, mas é uma nova página, ele carrega a página de novo ai.

Comment: Veja se isto ajuda, http://andornagy.com/active-class-navigation-menu/, você precisa adicionar a class active conforme a página ativa

Comment: Consegui, vou adicionar uma resposta com a minha solução :D

Comment: Que bom que deu certo, :)